# Which package should an enum, which is a part of a domain entity, be kept in a Java project?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

In my case, I have a java package - *domain* with JPA entity classes.
One of these entities, say Employee, has an attribute - **status**. **status** will always be from the set {ACTIVE, INACTIVE}, hence I have defined an enum - *Status*.

I know this is a small thing, but I was thinking whether this enum (which has no table mapped in the RDBMS database), be kept in *domain* package itself, or should it be kept somewhere else so that *domain* contains only the actual domain classes.

Comment: You can define enum in database and map your enum with database enum

Answer (score 1):

Simple put it depends on your taste.

If this enum is only used for the purpose of defining the status of a single class - in your case `Employee` then I would put it in a subpackage of `domain`.

For example:

- *.domain.enums (for all enums of that kind)
- *.domain.model (for all entity classes)